# Object Styles in Fireworks CS6

Tags: adobe-fireworks, style, character-styles

Is there a way to create object, character, and paragraph styles (etc.) in Fireworks, the same way that one creates styles in InDesign? There must be a way as this is a commonly needed function, but I cannot seem to find it in the Window dropdown.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. Fireworks is now deprecated and I don't believe Adobe ever added any Character or Paragraph Style features to it.

Maybe there's some third party plug in, but I *highly* doubt it.

Comment: Wow amazing that by CS6 they didn't think that designers would want to re-use elements. In either case, any suggestions within the Creative Cloud suite that are similar? Any recommendations within Adobe in general? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Nothing is *really* similar to fireworks. Adobe is pushing Edge, which I haven't really explored. The thought behind the deprecation is they have Illustrator, Photoshop, and now Edge and the Fireworks market was the smallest. Realize that even Photoshop didn't have character and paragraph styles until the CC version.

Comment: Ok cool. Yeh I'm an Illustrator/InDesign guy myself but just walked into a project created in Fireworks. Sweet ;-) .. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Whaa? they took out character and paragraph? Glad I'm still using CS4 :)

Comment: @kcdwayne You're saying you **have** character and paragraph styles in **Fireworks**?